# Unable to get value from TableRow's EditText of tableLayout in android

Tags: android

I've created a tablelayout that has multiple rows of four columns (3 TextView and 1 EditText). My problem is that when I iterate through all rows, I'm able to get textview values but can not get values of EditText.
My code is as below.
XMl Code:

```
<ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/Grid_layout" >

       <TableLayout
           android:id="@+id/header"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
           android:background="@android:color/black" >

           <TableRow>

               <TextView
                   android:layout_margin="1dp"
                   android:layout_weight="2"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:text="Item Name"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                   android:textSize="10sp" />

               <TextView
                   android:layout_margin="1dp"
                   android:layout_weight="2"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:text="Rack"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                   android:textSize="10sp" />

               <TextView
                   android:layout_margin="1dp"
                   android:layout_weight="2"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:text="Sale Rate"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                   android:textSize="10sp" />

               <TextView
                   android:layout_margin="1dp"
                   android:layout_weight="2"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:text="Sys. Stock"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                   android:textSize="10sp"
                   android:visibility="gone" />

               <EditText
                   android:layout_margin="1dp"
                   android:layout_weight="2"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:text="Phy. Stock"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                   android:textSize="10sp" />
           </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>

JAVA Code:

public void writeJSON() {

        try {
            ArrayList<EditText> metl = new ArrayList<EditText>();

            for (int i = 1; i < tableLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                TableRow mRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(i);

                TextView firstTextView = (TextView) mRow.getChildAt(3);
                String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();

                if (mRow.getChildAt(4) instanceof EditText) {
                    EditText secondTextView = (EditText) mRow.getChildAt(4);
                    String secondText = secondTextView.getText().toString();

                }
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Could not create or Open the database");
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance
Gulbaz

Comment: First of all, don't use table layout until you have no other ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

First of all use id in your xml file for you Views. As for me is more convenient to use if you define all of them in onCreate and then use where you want. For Examle: `EditText yourTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);`

EditText extends from TextView. You can get Text from them like this: `yourEditText.getText().toString()`